# Where is the method "setIsHandle" is defined?

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, blocks

I am unable to find the `setIsHandle` method ie defined inside `action` tag in `page.xml` under the node `page_one_column`.

```
<action method="setIsHandle"><applied>1</applied></action>
```

And what is purpose of using this ?

Comments state that it  **"Mark root page block that template is applied"**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no method `setIsHandle`.
It's a magic setter. It's equivalent to `->setData('is_handle', 1)`.

The value set by this, is later retrieved using `getIsHandle` that is equivalent with `->getData('is_handle')` in the [`Mage_Page_Helper_Layout::applyTemplate`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Page/Helper/Layout.php#L77) method.

Comment: You do not give time to answer the question.... :).. More faster than me :)

Comment: cool thanks much @marius , where it is used ? I mean purpose

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but it's something related to the layout of the root block.

Comment: By setting `is_handle` to 1 before the method Marius mentioned is executed you can avoid that a page layout is applied. Page layout in this context means something like the design tabs for CMS pages, categories or products.